# SQL: получить значение поля + инкремент

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне получить значение folder2 в таблице и после этого сразу же инкрементировать это значение на +1. Важно, чтобы при большом количестве одновременных запросов полученные значения folder2 не повторялись.

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | folder1 | folder2|
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |  235    |  13    |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Запрос в php я бы сделал так:

```
   $sql_query1 = "SELECT folder2 from tbl_name";

   $sql_query2 = "UPDATE tbl_name SET folder2 = folder2 + 1"
```

Но, что если между $sql_query1 и sql_query2 пройдёт какое-то время, а другие пользователи также будут выполнять скрипт. Тогда у какого-то количества пользователей будет совпадение значений folder2.

Как этого можно избежать?

Спасибо!

Comment: блокировать таблицу для записи когда ктото работает с ней.. но сильно замедлит работу в общем когда много пользователей

Comment: @Volodymyr А можно как-то одним запросом? SQL сервер выполняет запросы синхронно или асинхронно? Т.е. важно понимать все запросы становятся в очередь. Либо каждый запрос работает независимо от другого?

Comment: Совпадений не будет. Но в первом запросе Вы можете получить некорректное значение. А зачем Вам это все? Чего Вы пытаетесь достичь?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, Я пытаюсь, но безуспешно разработать систему каталогизации картинок на сервере. Пользователь загружает файлы на сервер. Для пользователя я создам директорию исходя из значения folder2. Т.е. он загрузил файлы, я получил значение folder2 и сразу установил значение для следующего пользователя и т.д.

Comment: @Pavel Вам нужна отдельная таблица `folders` со своим инкрементным первичным ключом

Comment: @AntonShchyrov инкремент будет увеличиваться только при использовании INSERT? А для folder1 будет другая таблица, например если folder2 достигнет максимума? Слышал ещё, что int имеет некоторые ограничения по значениям. А bigint как-то сказывается на скорости?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov И ещё вопрос. Файловые системы имеют некоторые ограничения на количество папок в папке. Если использовать автоинкремент, то он этого не поймёт. Например, мы решили, что в папке folder максимум будет 100 папок. Тогда folder1 мы увеличиваем на 1 и folder2 должен начать с нуля. В этом случае автоинкремент, мне кажется не подходит

Comment: @Pavel Только при INSERT. Но если Вы после каждой заливки создаете папку, то вот Вам и INSERT. `INTEGER UNSIGNED` имеет предел в 4 миллиарда. Если Вы будете создавать новую запись ежесекундно, то Вам понадобится 136 лет, чтобы достичь переполнения. Использование `BIGINT` на скорость почти не влияет

Comment: @Pavel Что мешает в таблице folders хранить реальные имена папок? Тогда и два поля folder1, folder2 не нужны. Достаточно одного folder_id

Comment: @AntonShchyrov folder_id подразумевает конкретное значение. Например 5 000 000. Т.е. в корневой папке /uploads/ будет 5 миллионов подпапок. Мне кажется не получится, потому что есть ограничение на количество папок в папке. Поэтому я хотел поставить определенные рамки в создании папок и привязать их к id пользователя.

Comment: @Pavel Folders: [{id: 50000; name: "upload/asd/zsd"}, .. {id: 100000; name: "upload/bfg/xvf"}]

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Брать unix time+ рандомное значение + md5 хэш и поделить строку на 2 части? В принципе, очень хороший вариант. А можно как-то сделать последовательность? Например для одного пользователя /235/122/, для другого /235/123/, для третьего /235/124/ для n-го /255/32/

Comment: @Pavel добавить в таблицу folders поле user_id. Еще раз folder_id это **не имя папки** это **идентификатор**, а имя папки Вы можете генерировать по произвольному алгоритму. И, кстати, Ваш алгоритм с хешем будет давать сбои

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Если folder_id уникальный идентификатор записи, то каким образом можно обеспечить уникальность путей сгенерированных по произвольному алгоритму?

Comment: @Pavel SomeStr + folder_id

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Спасибо!

Comment: Определеяетесь с тем сколько папок вы хотите держать с одной папке (тут еще вопрос не в ограничениях ОС, а в том, что когда файлов много чтение начинает тормозить. я бы старался более 1 тыс не делать). А дальше спокойно выдаете id вставляя записи. Остаток от деления id на 1000 - нижний уровень, целая часть от деления на 1000 верхний уровень. вот и весь алгоритм

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет блокировка таблиц:

```
$sql_query1 = "LOCK TABLE folder2 WRITE";
$sql_query2 = "SELECT folder2 from tbl_name";
$sql_query3 = "UPDATE tbl_name SET folder2 = folder2 + 1"
$sql_query4 = "UNLOCK TABLES";
```

В этом случае, даже если между query2 и query3 будет запущен SQL-запрос другим пользователем(подключением), он будет ждать, пока не будет снята блокировка пользователем(подключением), который её установил, запросом в query4.

Если таблица типа InnoDB - то можно поставить блокировку на строку, что будет менее затратно по ресурсам, но с этим вопросом вам лучше разобраться подробнее, прочитав про "Транзакции InnoDB".